# Xamarin Forms - How to write unit test for tabbed pages in xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, ui-testing

Can anybody give pointers on how to write automated unit test for tabbed pages in xamarin Forms?

From the documentation provided I have learned that we need to provide automation Id to the control and write the tap command to get focus on the control and input data.

But this doesn't work for tabbed pages. Tried directly giving the tab name and executing tap command, but that doesn't work too.

Comment: You meant UI Test?

Comment: @apineda Yes, UI test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[Test]
public void MyTabTest()
{
    app.Tap(x => x.Marked("Your Tab Title 1"));
    app.Tap(x => x.Marked("Your Tab Title 2"));
    app.Tap(x => x.Marked("Your Tab Title 3"));
}
```

Also whenever you don't know a command for a UITest the [Xamarin TestRecorder](https://www.xamarin.com/test-cloud/recorder) is gonna be your best friend.

Hope this works.

Comment: Thanks it's working fine. I tried with page name and not the title. Thanks again.

Comment: What if there where another text with the same title?
What if you wanna tap on both of them!

AutomationId doesn't work for toolbarItem and tabbedPage trigger view